# Filter divs jquery wihen select one or multiple options

Tags: jquery, html, filter

I am trying to create a filter with multiple checkbox in jquery but is not working.

I have 4 check boxes ( board type), and the hotel list is displayed on my site as `<article></article>`.

I want to create a filter, when a box is ticked to hide the articles that corresponds to the unchecked boxes.

http://jsfiddle.net/qvmskejq/1/

Comment: Please consider revising your post, provide some code and a description of what you are trying to achieve, what you have tried already and ask a question

Comment: What is suppposed to happen? Why are you trying to use `.change` on an `article`? and `#board-filter` doesnt exist in your fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You have some structural HTML issues (inputs are self closing & your `articles` were not closed). Once you fix that you could loop through each of them and show and hide their corresponding `article` by pulling their `value`:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(e){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
       var grabVal = $(this).val();
       if(!$(this).is(":checked")){
           $("article[data-board='"+grabVal+"']").hide(); //show article that was clicked
        }else{
           $("article[data-board='"+grabVal+"']").show(); //hide article that was clicked
        }
    });

    if(!$("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")){
     $("article").show(); //show all if no checkboxs clicked
    }

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qvmskejq/3/)

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="trigger" id="ALL" name="ALL" value="all">Toate</input>
<input type="checkbox" class="trigger" id="RO" name="RO" value="room">Room Only</input>
<input type="checkbox" class="trigger" id="BB" name="BB" value="breakfast">Breakfast Buffet</input>
<input type="checkbox" class="trigger" id="AI" name="AI" value="allinclusive">All Inclusive</input>
<input type="checkbox" class="trigger" id="AI" name="AI" value="halfboard">Half Board</input>

<article data-board="room">
    <p>Room Only</p>
</article>
<article data-board="breakfast">
    <p>Breakfast Buffet</p>
</article>
    <article data-board="allinclusive">
    <p>All Inclusive</p>
</article>
    <article data-board="allinclusive">
    <p>All Inclusive</p>
</article>
    <article data-board="halfboard">
    <p>Half Board</p>
</article>
    <article data-board="halfboard">
    <p>Half Boardy</p>
</article>
```

**javascript**

```
   $('article').hide();
$('.trigger').removeClass('checked');
$('.trigger').on('touchstart click',function(){
        var self = $(this);
        if(self.prop('id')=='ALL') {
            if(self.hasClass('checked')){
                $('article').hide(); 
                self.removeClass('checked');
            } else {
            self.addClass('checked');
        $('article').show(); 
            }
        } else {
          if(self.hasClass('checked')){
                $('article[data-board="' + self.val() + '"]').hide(); 
                self.removeClass('checked');
            } else {
            self.addClass('checked');
        $('article[data-board="' + self.val() + '"]').show(); 
            }
        }
    });
```

**fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/qvmskejq/6/